# Is there a limit of the number of legend labels passed to ArcGIS server print service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing, legend

[image: Image with legend disappeared]

Is there any limit on the ArcGIS print service for the number of legend labels? I am using ArcGIS server 10.2 and ArcGIS Javascript version 3.10 and am able to print with legend labels (item descriptions) when there are about 60 different items even though the they are not complete. However, when there are more, all the labels disappeared like the image above. Anyone know if there were any limit or anyway to set the limit?

Comment: From memory, when u perform a print, a MXD gets created under arcgisjobs folder.  Id suggest opening one that failed and investigating the legend in there directly.  Also, check the fitting strategy of the legend (see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Working_with_legends/00s900000023000000/)